# Lodash : orderBy how to put at the top of the ordered list documents without field by which we order?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, lodash

I'm using firebase & firestore and I have an old collection called `singers` which contains documents with some construction e.g.

```
name: string
genre: string,
...
```

Now I need to order these docs from that collection on the frontend and I need to do it from the oldest to the newest, but I can't do it without a field like `createdAt` because firestore doesn't provide any information about when document was created.

**What I did**

Firstly added field `createdAt` in registration, now the new created singer have field `createdAt` but the old ones don't have it. So I wanted to order it that order:

1. All singers without field `createdAt` with random order or by any other field
2. Singers with field `createdAt` order from the oldest to the newest

**Example data:**

```
const singers = [
  {
    name: 'Phil',
    genre: 'Pop',
    ...
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Bom',
    genre: 'Rock',
    ...
  }, 
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    genre: 'Hiphop',
    createdAt: 190000000,
    ...
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    genre: 'Hiphop',
    createdAt: 195000000,
    ...
  },
]
```

```
const sortedSingers = orderBy(
    singers, // collection with all singers from firestore 
    [singer => (singer.createdAt?? singer.name)],
    ['desc'],
  );
```

And it render in wrong order:

1. Tom
2. John
3. Bom
4. Phil

And I want to order like this:

1. Bom/Phil
2. Bom/Phil
3. Tom
4. John

How to make `orderBy` make documents without ordered field to be at the beginning of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this:

```
  const singerCreatedAt: any = singers.map((singer: Singer) =>
    singer.createdAt
      ? { ...singer, createdAt: singer.createdAt?.toDate() }
      : { ...singer, createdAt: new Date(190000000000) },
  );

  const sortedSingers = orderBy(singerCreatedAt, ['createdAt', 'asc']);
```